# html table for a newsletter

Tags: html, css, newsletter

I'm trying to reproduce this for a Newsletter, with the text and images centred.

[image]

This is what I have so far

[image]

I was trying to add the  border-collapse: collapse; property and also to add border left and right but I'm stacked. If you have any suggestions how to create the vertical lines and cantered the text and images I would deeply appreciate any help.

```
            <table class="outer-table-2">
                <tr>
                    <td class="three-column">
                        <div class="section">
                            <table width="100%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="inner-td">
                                        <table class="content">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="text">
                                                    <p>01628531300</p>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div> 
                        <div class="section">
                            <table width="100%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="inner-td">
                                        <table class="content">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <div id="callout">
                                                        <ul class="social">
                                                            <li><a href="index.html#" target="_blank"><img src="facebook.png"></a></li>
                                                            <li><a href="index.html#" target="_blank"><img src="twitter.png"></a></li>
                                                            <li><a href="index.html#" target="_blank"><img src="linkedin.png"></a></li>
                                                        </ul>
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div> 
                        <div class="section">
                            <table width="100%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="inner-td">
                                        <table class="content">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="text">
                                                    <p><a href="wwww.cdvi.co.uk">www.cdvi.co.uk</a><p>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div> 
                    </td>
                </tr> 
            </table> 

<style>
.outer-table-2 {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 670px;
    margin: 12px auto;
    border: 3px solid #00467f;


}
.three-column {

}
.three-column .section {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color: #FFFFf;
}

.three-column .social {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;

}
.outer-table-2 p {
    margin:10px 10px 10px 40px;
    color: #00467f;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 1000 !important;
    line-height: 10px;


}


.middle-table {
   margin: auto;
   padding-top: 10px;


}

.middle-table img{
    width: 120px;
    height: 80px;

}
</style>
```

Comment: Why so many nested tables? It looks form your image that you only need one.

Comment: Those external links will be dead in no time, making this question not very useful for others in the future. You should try to distill what you want down to text that is provided locally.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are massively over-complicating this. You only need one table to recreate a layout similar to your image.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr {
  height: 60px;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
}

.b-t {
  border-top: 5px solid darkblue;
}

.b-l {
  border-left: 5px solid darkblue;
}

.b-r {
  border-right: 5px solid darkblue;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="b-t b-r">01628531300</td>
    <td class="b-t">
      <ul class="social">
        <li><a href="index.html#" target="_blank"><img src="facebook.png"></a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html#" target="_blank"><img src="twitter.png"></a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html#" target="_blank"><img src="linkedin.png"></a></li>
      </ul>
    </td>
    <td class="b-t b-l">
      <a href="wwww.cdvi.co.uk">www.cdvi.co.uk</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```